# R paste using a loop

Tags: r, paste

I am generating an input file for software. I ran into an inconsistency in `paste0()` function. Here are my example list of names.

```
vars <- c("1234_AS_SA1_PCNS","2345_AS_SA2_UDA", "3823_AS_SA3_CL")
```

I would like to print this:

```
 "Equal = (1234_AS_SA1_PCNS, Slope[0]),
          (2345_AS_SA2_UDA, Slope[0]),
          (3823_AS_SA3_CL, Slope[0]);"
```

I tried this but it did not do the job. SOmehow, "Equal" gets to the end.

```
paste0("Equal = ", 
       
       for(i in 1:length(vars)) {
         Equal <- paste0("(",vars[i], ", Slope[0])", ",")
         print(Equal)
       })


[1] "(1234_AS_SA1_PCNS, Slope[0]),"
[1] "(2345_AS_SA2_UDA, Slope[0]),"
[1] "(3823_AS_SA3_CL, Slope[0]),"
[1] "Equal = "
```

This function does not employ `","`s correctly as well as a `";"` at the end.

Any thoughts?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you need `cat(paste0("Equal = ", paste("(", vars, ", Slope[0])", collapse=", ", sep="")))`

Comment: I hope you aren't trying to generate R code by mainpulating text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do this without a loop as `paste` is vectorized

```
cat(paste0("Equal = ", paste("(", vars, ", Slope[0])",
        collapse=",\n ", sep=""), ";"))
Equal = (1234_AS_SA1_PCNS, Slope[0]),
 (2345_AS_SA2_UDA, Slope[0]),
 (3823_AS_SA3_CL, Slope[0]);
```

If we need to have double quotes at the end

```
cat(dQuote(paste0("Equal = ", paste("(", vars, ", Slope[0])",
        collapse=",\n ", sep=""), ";"), FALSE))
"Equal = (1234_AS_SA1_PCNS, Slope[0]),
 (2345_AS_SA2_UDA, Slope[0]),
 (3823_AS_SA3_CL, Slope[0]);"
```

---

Or may be

```
cat(dQuote(paste0("Equal = ", paste(sprintf('"(%s, Slope[0])"', vars), collapse=",\n ", sep="")), FALSE))
"Equal = "(1234_AS_SA1_PCNS, Slope[0])",
 "(2345_AS_SA2_UDA, Slope[0])",
 "(3823_AS_SA3_CL, Slope[0])""
```

Comment: Oh actually, I wanted to have quotes (") beginning and the end. Is that a minor edit in your code?

Comment: @amisos55 Yes, you can wrap with `dQuote(paste0(....), FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks that works just fine. May I ask one last thing? `"Equal = (1234_AS_SA1_PCNS, Slope[0])",
          "(2345_AS_SA2_UDA, Slope[0])",
          "(3823_AS_SA3_CL, Slope[0]);"` is quoting every element possible? I apologize that this was not what I asked in the original question.

Comment: @amisos55 In that case, you can use `dQuote` on the `dQuote(vars, FALSE)` within the `paste`

Comment: ignoring `"Equal = "` , I used this `cat(paste("(", dQuote(vars, FALSE), ", Slope[0])", collapse=",\n ", sep=""), ";")` but this gave this:  `("1234_AS_SA1_PCNS", Slope[0]),
 ("2345_AS_SA2_UDA", Slope[0]),
 ("3823_AS_SA3_CL", Slope[0]) ;`. I was looking to have `"(1234_AS_SA1_PCNS, Slope[0])",
 "(2345_AS_SA2_UDA, Slope[0])",
 "(3823_AS_SA3_CL, Slope[0]);"`

Comment: @amisos55 what is your expected for that

Comment: @amisos55 `"(1234_AS_SA1_PCNS", Slope[0])"`. I see some quotes out of place in your expected.  e.g. your opening quote is outside the `(`, while the closing doesn't involve `)`

Comment: The last part of my last comment after `I was looking to have...` is my desired output.

Comment: @amisos55.  Is that correct or is there any typo on that part

Comment: @amisos55 updaed the post

Comment: I have all versions that I need up there. thanks for your time

Comment: is there a way to convert the output as class of character ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a for loop to "expand" into function arguments like that. *Especially* not by trying to `print` them. This isn't Bash.

```r
vars <- c("1234_AS_SA1_PCNS","2345_AS_SA2_UDA", "3823_AS_SA3_CL")

# Generate each "(<var>, Slope[0])" section
sections <- as.list(paste0("(", vars, ", Slope[0])"))

# Join the sections with ", "
sections_str <- do.call(paste, c(sections, sep = ", "))

# Construct the final string
result <- paste0("Equal = ", part2)

print(result)
```